# toggle outer div together with inner div

Tags: javascript, html, css, nested

I have a page (e.g. "page1") with multiple divs and some are nested within other divs. All divs are hidden by default and toggle on by clicking a specific link (or off when clicked again). To see a nested div, you first have to open the outer div.

Reduced example is [here](http://sigloch-coll.de/fachgebiete2.html)

Now my customer wants to have a link from another page (e.g. "page2") to a specific nested div on page1 and show it. This means that the outer div has to open too. How can this be accomplished?

With

```
<a href="page1.html#divid5">clickfordivid5</a>
```

The nested div opens but stays hidden of course, since the outer div is still hidden. Can I toggle both divs with on link?

Thanks so much!

*Additional info:*

This script is used:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

function toggle(id) { 
   var el = document.getElementById(id); 
   if (el.style.display == "block") { 
      el.style.display = "none"; 
   } else {
      el.style.display = "block";
   } 
} 
</script>
```

and then

```
<a href="javascript:toggle('divid5');">
```

with

```
<div class="ToggleTarget" id="divid5">
```

Comment: In the code that opens the div, could you also go up the dom to the parent and open that too?

Comment: How are pages constructed? What's your method for toggling the visibility? How are you pulling URL parameters to target a div??? Yes I could spend > 30 minutes examining your link to answer these, but including relevant info in the question is helpful.

Comment: Sorry. Thought I had all relevant infos :-(


this script is used:
           <script type="text/javascript">
            function toggle(id) {
                var el = document.getElementById(id);
                if (el.style.display == "block") {
                    el.style.display = "none";
                } else {
                    el.style.display = "block";
                }
            }
        </script> 


and then
    a href="javascript:toggle('divid5');">

with
            <div class="ToggleTarget" id="divid5">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of short and better ways to accomplish it with jQuery ,but I checked your site you are not using jQuery library.

To accomplish it with javascript add a class to all the tags which needs to be opened at the same time, for example add a class called **same** to child and its parent div as well and keep the display of that class as none(add .same{display:none} in your css file).Now add following code at the footer of the webpage having those divs:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if(window.location.hash.substring(1)){
     var cols = document.getElementsByClassName(window.location.hash.substring(1));
          for(i=0; i<cols.length; i++) {
            cols[i].style.display = 'block';

            }
    }
</script>
```

On the other page add the hash link how you already added but with the class which needs to be kept open:

```
<a href="page1.html#same">clickfordivid5</a>
```

It should work.

Comment: Thanks for you input! It works nicely for one link. 

What if I have more links to other divs within the first parent div? 

I have div 1 (parent) and div 2, div3 and div4 as children of div1.
>div1
>>div2
>>div3
>>div3

Now on page 2 I have three links: one should (on page1) open div2 together with div1, another div3 together with div1 and the third div4 together with div1.

It would be nice if div1 could have multiple classes (same1, same 2 and same3), but as far as I know, this is not possible?

Comment: We can add multiple classes and it works as well but if the same property is added to all the classes then the class added last will override the previous classes.So if you want to add multiple classes you can add like class="same1 same2 same3" . The code I sent to you is adding an inline display:block on run time and inline style has the highest priority in execution so it should work doesnt matter which class you are passing.

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks a lot :-)